# UITableView Delegate Methods Not Being Called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UIViewController that has  UISegmentedControl that displays 3 other views depending on what segment is selected via:

```
- (void)segmentedControl:(SVSegmentedControl*)segmentedControl didSelectIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    if (index == 0)
    {
        MyTableViewController *myViewController = [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyTableViewController" bundle:nil]; 
        myViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0.,40.,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height-40.);
        self.theTableViewController = myViewController;
        [myViewController release];
        [self.view addSubview: self.theTableViewController.view]; 
    }
```

But when I select a row from a cell on this view, it does not push to the next.  This is because I've manually added that view controller's view to the view hierarch so its not being managed by the navcontroller.  I think I need to make a property or something can anyone chime in?

Edit:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SpecificExerciseTableViewController *specificExerciseTableViewController = [[SpecificExerciseTableViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SpecificExerciseTableViewController" bundle:nil];
    specificExerciseTableViewController.exerciseArray = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"exercises"];
    specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleName = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"muscleName"];

    NSString *muscleURL = [[self.muscleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"musclePicture"];
    specificExerciseTableViewController.muscleURL = muscleURL;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:specificExerciseTableViewController animated:YES];
    [specificExerciseTableViewController release];
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do something like [[self navigationController] pushViewController:musclesTableViewController animated:YES] instead?

Comment: why are you creating a MyTableViewController but then adding muscledTableViewController.view?

Comment: @Serigio, sorry, that was just a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: onnoweb, I am not pushing this view, I want it to appear in the space in the same view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

could you add more detail about your delegate? when do you set it? how is `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` defined?

I guess that inside of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `self.navigationController` will be nil, since that controller has not been pushed. So, you should access the navigation controller through the main view controller where you are adding the table view as subview.

Comment: I added `[self.musclesTableViewController viewDidLoad];` after adding the subView, but the problem persists.  When I load this view on its own, it functions fine.

Comment: Sergio, keep in mind that MyTableViewController works fine when its in its own tab. Its just not pushing when I add it as a subView to this view we are working with. It has to do with it not being added to the navigation controller i believe.

Answer (score 0):

The method `-addSubview:` on `UIView` is expecting a `UIView` to be passed in. In this case, you're passing in an instance of `MyTableViewController`.

Try this:

`[self.view addSubview:self.theTableViewController.view];`

Comment: Hey Mark, I actually am doing that already, i just forgot to add it to the question.

Comment: Can you post the code for `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from MyTableViewController?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that MyTableViewController works fine when its in its own tab.  Its just not pushing when I add it as a subView to this view we are working with.  It has to do with it not being added to the navigation controller i believe.

Comment: I'm aware of that. That's why I want to see how you're attempting to push to a new view controller in `-tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Maybe we can work out a way to walk up looking for any existing UINavigationController to use for pushing. It's gonna be a bit of a hack though.

Comment: Ok I'm adding that to the question, 1 sec.  And I can push to the next view controller regularly, it doesn't have to stay as a subview.

Comment: This is probably not the answer you want to hear, but I would re-think this design. It will probably be easier to just have one view controller managing the various views that can be switched to with the segmented control. Use the segmented control to just hide or show certain views as needed. To cut down on code clutter, roll any necessary delegate/datasource methods for these views into their own separate classes that are retained by the primary view controller.

Comment: Mark, thanks, you may be right.  Can you chat with me for a second?

Comment: @MarkAdams let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1811/discussion-between-jon-and-mark-adams)